# How to develop http proxy server with username and password authentication

Tags: http, go

I want to write a http proxy with authentication in golang but I couldn't find any example.
Here is what I trid but didn't work: (I get `Error parsing basic auth`)

```golang
server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         "0.0.0.0:8080",
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

            b, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
            if err == nil {
                fmt.Println("dump", string(b))
            } else {
                fmt.Println("dump error", err)
            }

            u, p, ok := r.BasicAuth()
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("Error parsing basic auth")
                w.WriteHeader(401)
                return
            }
            if u != "USERNAME"{
                fmt.Printf("Username provided is correct: %s\n", u)
                w.WriteHeader(401)
                return
            }
            if p != "PASSWORD" {
                fmt.Printf("Password provided is correct: %s\n", u)
                w.WriteHeader(401)
                return
            }
            if r.Method == http.MethodConnect {
                handleTunneling(w, r)
            } else {
                handleHTTP(w, r)
            }
        }),
        // Disable HTTP/2.
        TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler)),
}

log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
```

I tested the application with firefox and foxyproxy
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJGlP.png)

Comment: https://vikaspogu.dev/posts/golang-basicauth-gin/ Useful example using Gin and basic auth middleware

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Authentication](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235) has two headers for providing authentication information: [Authorization](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.2) and [Proxy-Authorization](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.4).

Authorization header:

```
The "Authorization" header field allows a user agent to authenticate
itself with an origin server -- usually, but not necessarily, after
receiving a 401 (Unauthorized) response.  Its value consists of
credentials containing the authentication information of the user
agent for the realm of the resource being requested.
```

Proxy-Authorization:

```
The "Proxy-Authorization" header field allows the client to identify
itself (or its user) to a proxy that requires authentication.  Its
value consists of credentials containing the authentication
information of the client for the proxy and/or realm of the resource
being requested.
```

[Request.BasicAuth()](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.BasicAuth) is for "Authorization" header, not for "Proxy-Authorization" header.

```
BasicAuth returns the username and password provided in the request's Authorization header, if the request uses HTTP Basic Authentication. See RFC 2617, Section 2.
```

For parsing "Proxy-Authorization" header you can copy [parseBasicAuth()](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/net/http/request.go;l=950) function from [request.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/net/http/request.go).

```
func ProxyBasicAuth(header http.Header) (username, password string, ok bool) {
    auth := header.Get("Proxy-Authorization")
    if auth == "" {
        return "", "", false
    }
    return parseBasicAuth(auth)
}

// parseBasicAuth parses an HTTP Basic Authentication string.
// "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" returns ("Aladdin", "open sesame", true).
func parseBasicAuth(auth string) (username, password string, ok bool) {
    const prefix = "Basic "
    // Case insensitive prefix match. See Issue 22736.
    if len(auth) < len(prefix) || !asciiEqualFold(auth[:len(prefix)], prefix) {
        return "", "", false
    }
    c, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(auth[len(prefix):])
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", false
    }
    cs := string(c)
    username, password, ok = strings.Cut(cs, ":")
    if !ok {
        return "", "", false
    }
    return username, password, true
}

// EqualFold is strings.EqualFold, ASCII only. It reports whether s and t
// are equal, ASCII-case-insensitively.
func asciiEqualFold(s, t string) bool {
    if len(s) != len(t) {
        return false
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if asciiLower(s[i]) != asciiLower(t[i]) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

// lower returns the ASCII lowercase version of b.
func asciiLower(b byte) byte {
    if 'A' <= b && b <= 'Z' {
        return b + ('a' - 'A')
    }
    return b
}
```

[Here](https://go.dev/play/p/OOVDL0ZzSUC) is the source code with minor changes. You can also check out packages like [elazarl/goproxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy) and  [snail007/goproxy](https://github.com/snail007/goproxy).